# iOS device as HTTP Server

Tags: ios, file-upload, download, httpserver, cocoahttpserver

I am new to network programming. I want an iOS device to work as an HTTP server and display contents of document directory and having directory operations like create, delete, putting contents on directory on server which also reflects in iOS device directory also.

I got `CocoaHTTPServer` reference for this task. But not getting idea to implement as my above requirement.

Can Anyone Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using RoutingHTTPServer `https://github.com/mattstevens/RoutingHTTPServer`so that you can use your iOS device as a server and respond to RESTful requests.